# How do I draw concurrent custom shapes in flutter like this?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, adobe

I want to create the shapes which are at the bottom of the design, but I'm unable to think of an approach I tried transform.rotate on a container but there are overflow issues. Any kind of help is appreciated. Thanks!

[Here's the link to the design, that I want to create.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pmiZy.png)

Answer (score 0):

There are a few solutions for this UI:

1. You can export the background as an image.

- Pros: Save time, easy.
- Cons: Performance is not good as solution 2 below (for loading image and app size).

2. Use canvas (and paint) to draw those curves. If you're not familiar with Canvas in Flutter, you can check [this tutorial](https://blog.codemagic.io/flutter-custom-painter/).

- Pros: performance is better (render time is faster and app size is smaller).
- Cons: time consuming, sometimes you will need to have good maths knowledge to draw complex UI.

Comment: Thanks, but Do you have any idea about the math behind it? Like a previous code snippet that can apply in this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

I found a better option for creating custom shapes.

There is this website, which converts shapes to code.

Here's the link: https://fluttershapemaker.com

It saves a lot of time. Thanks.